# Toolbar on top of layout when using CoordinatorLayout, Swipe2Refresh and WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-design-library, swiperefreshlayout

Im having issues with the toolbar being display ontop of the webview and i am trying to figure out how to remedy this. Any and all feedback is greatly appreciated.

### webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ui.activities.WebActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_web" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### content_web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here some code regarding how i am setting up the webview.

```
public class WebActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Bind(R.id.webview)
    WebView webView;
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.swipe_refresh)
    public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            webViewUrl = AUTH_URL;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView = initWebView();
                    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);
                }
            });

        } else {
            webViewUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_URL,AUTH_URL);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Any and all help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layouts in a `CoordinatorLayout` need to define a `layout_behavior`. Change your content to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```